# how to create buttons in the .java file

Tags: android

the aim of my program is to get the user to create a deck of flash cards. Then when the user wants to practice the deck they can click the button corresponding to the deck they created and practice. But i'm not sure how get the button on the screen after the new deck is created. Can I create buttons in the .java file if so how to I define their placement or do I have to make the buttons in the xml file and then set the to invisible until they are needed? Thank you any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where is your code? What research have you done?

Answer (score 0):

The latter sounds like the better implementation. Use a `FrameLayout` and add the Buttons as the topmost item in your view (ie. bottom most item in the layout, see [FrameLayout documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html); it's z indexed.) Set them to be `View.GONE` by default and change them to `View.VISIBLE` when the buttons are clicked for the corresponding deck.